# Simple StackPolicy always invalid on CloudFormation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I've been attempting to upload the following Stack Policy:

```
{
  "StackPolicy" : {
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "Update:*",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Resource" : "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect" : "Deny",
        "Action" : "Update:*",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Resource" : "LogicalResourceId/ReleaseDeploy"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I receive
[image]

I've also simplified it to the point of having only the `Allow` Effect on all `Resources` and removed all whitespace, still get the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
{"StackPolicy":{"Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow", "Action":"Update:*", "Principal":"*", "Resource":"*"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example provided [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-cloudformation-security-best-practices/) it looks like the `StackPolicy` key is not supposed to be there, there seems to be 1 excess level in your JS Object. Also have a look and check if providing the `Version` attribute makes a difference.

An example of what the policy should look like:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[        
            "cloudformation:*"
        ],
    "Resource":"*"
    },
    {
        "Effect":"Deny",
        "Action":[        
            "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
            "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
        ],
        "Resource":"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:123456789012:stack/MyProductionStack/*"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Removing the StackPolicy attribute level worked! No version appears to be necessary. Thanks!